# Installing a GUI over a running Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, graphical-user-interface

The server is Ubuntu Server 10.04 have asterisk-1.6.2.2.tar.gz installed.

I have read that most of the GUI for Asterisk administration are something more than simple GUIs, and overwrite the previous asterisk configuration at the time of installation. can give me a guide or tell me some experience with something similar

Answer (score 0):

You can install [FreePBX](http://www.freepbx.org/support/documentation/installation) on top of Ubuntu but CentOS is the distro of choice.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes but overwrites all settings. I need avoid this behavoir

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any GUI that you would want to install over a running Asterisk installation unless you want to redo the configuration.  They all will need to overwrite your configuration files to handle things their way.